# Updating a JSTree using Knockout Custom Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, jstree

I'm trying to create a JSTree interface that uses Knockout JS as the viewmodel for the project.

I would like to be able to create/rename/delete nodes via the viewmodel where the JSTree 'building' happens in a custombinding.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to access the jstree in my viewmodel (while keeping the ui decoupled) so I can CRUD the nodes.

I obviously don't want to push new objects into an array but this was done as a proof of concept that the observableArray([]) can be used for the data.

http://jsfiddle.net/ascendantofrain/76cco3cs/41/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.createFolder">Create Folder</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.createFile">Create File</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.rename">Rename</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <pre data-bind="text: treeData"></pre>

    <div id="jstree_demo_div" data-bind="jstree: { data: treeData }"></div>

    <!-- <div id="jstree_demo_dev_attributes">
        <ul>
          <li>Attribute Reporting Group
            <ul>
              <li>Invoice Dates</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div> -->

</div>
```

### KNOCKOUT JS

```
function tree() {
    var self = this;

    self.createFolder = function (data) {
        self.treeData.push({
            'id': 'iPhone',
            'parent': 'device',
            'text': 'iPhone',
            'type': 'default'
        });
    };

    self.createFile = function (data) {
        self.treeData.push({
            'id': 'ios8',
            'parent': 'iPhone',
            'text': 'iOS 8',
            'type': 'file'
        });
    };

    self.rename = function (data) {
    };

    self.delete = function (data) {
    };

    self.treeData = ko.observableArray([
        { 'id': 'animal', 'parent': '#', 'text': 'Animals' },
        { 'id': 'device', 'parent': '#', 'text': 'Devices' },
        { 'id': 'dog', 'parent': 'animal', 'text': 'Dogs' }
    ]);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.jstree = {
    buildTree: function (element, treeData) {
        $(element).jstree('destroy');
        $(element).jstree({
            'core': {
                'animation': 0,
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': treeData
            },
            'types': {
                '#': {
                    'max_depth': 4,
                    'valid_children': ['root']
                },
                'level_1': {
                    'valid_children': ['default']
                },
                'level_2': {
                    'valid_children': ['file']
                },
                'file': {
                    'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-file'
                }
            },
            'plugins': [
                'search',
                'state',
                'types',
                'wholerow',
                'unique'
            ]
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var treeData = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.jstree.buildTree(element, treeData.data());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new tree());
```

Answer (score 6):

this is too late but take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/u4a7k5zu/20/

It's a modified version of your fiddle. Not sure if this what you were looking for. You might have already figured it out though. Maybe it might help someone else.

FIDDLE CODE:

```
function tree() {
var self = this;

//display actions in fiddle
self.consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
self.consoleLog = function (text) {
    $("#console-log").append($(self.consoleLine).html(text));
};
self.clearConsoleLog = function () {
    $("#console-log").html('');
};


self.tree = $('#jstree_demo_div'); //get jstree div
self.isNodeSelected = ko.observable(false);
self.selectedNode = ko.observable({});

//deselect all nodes
self.deselectAllNodes = function () {
    self.tree.jstree('deselect_all');
}

//keep track of selected node
self.tree.on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var node = self.tree.jstree().get_selected(true)[0]; //get current selected node
    if (typeof node !== 'undefined') {
        self.isNodeSelected(true);
        self.selectedNode(node);
        self.consoleLog('selected node id: ' + node.id + ', type: ' + node.type);
    } else {
        self.isNodeSelected(false);
    }
});

self.createFolderNode = function (data) {
    //node can be created on a preselected node or pass # to create a root node
    var node;
    var data;
    if (self.isNodeSelected()) 
    {
        node = self.selectedNode();
        data = {'id': Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1),
                    'text': 'iPhone', 'type': 'folder'};
    } 
    else
    {
        node = '#';
        data = {'id': Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1),
                'parent': '#',
                'text': 'New Root Node',
                'type' : 'root'
                 };            
    }
    //create node
    var id = self.tree.jstree("create_node", node, data, 'last');
    self.tree.jstree('open_node', node);
    self.tree.jstree('edit', id);

};

self.createFileNode = function (data) {
    //Below code only allows files to be created within folders.
    //Structure it as per createFolder method to create files at root
    var data = {
        'id': Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1),
            'text': 'iOS 8',
            'type': 'file'
    }
    //create file node
    var id = self.tree.jstree("create_node", self.selectedNode(), data, 'last');
    self.tree.jstree('open_node', self.selectedNode());
    self.tree.jstree('edit', id);
};

self.renameNode = function (data) {
    if(self.isNodeSelected()){
        self.tree.jstree('edit', self.selectedNode());
    }
    else{
        alert('please select a node to rename!');
    }
};

self.deleteNode = function (data) {
    if(self.isNodeSelected()){
        self.tree.jstree('delete_node', self.selectedNode());
    }
    else{
        alert('please select a node to delete!');
    }
};

self.treeData = ko.observableArray([{
    'id': 1,
        'parent': '#',
        'text': 'Animals',
    'type': '#'
}, {
    'id': 2,
        'parent': '#',
        'text': 'Devices',
        'type' : '#'
}, {
    'id': 'dog',
        'parent': 1,
        'text': 'Dogs',
        'type' : 'folder'
}]);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.jstree = {
buildTree: function (element, treeData) {
    $(element).jstree('destroy');
    $(element).jstree({
        'core': {
            'animation': 0,
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': treeData
        },
            'types': {
            '#': {
                'max_children': 10,
                'max_depth': 10,
                'valid_children': ['root', 'folder','file']
            },
                'folder': {
                'valid_children': ['folder','file']
            },
                'file': {
                    'icon': 'glyphicon glyphicon-file',
                    'max_depth': 0
            }
        },
            'plugins': [
            'search',
            'state',
            'types',
            'wholerow']
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var treeData = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    ko.bindingHandlers.jstree.buildTree(element, treeData.data());
}
};

ko.applyBindings(new tree());
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) This helped me to some extent... really appreciate it. One question; How can we integrate the drag and drop feature, so we could drag either folders and/or files to other folders? Other question, let's say we have 2 JSON file pulling from server with, one for folders and one for files, so how could we save the changes seamlessly without the user realises? Many thanks

Comment: @Farzad, The drag/drop feature is available as a plugin on the jstree.

Comment: @Farzad, 1st Q: Refer to the [jstree plugin](https://www.jstree.com/plugins/) page on how to include it.  2nd Q: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Pulling from the server or saving to the server or notifying the user of the changes? Can you clarify your 2nd question? Populating the jstree with json is covered [here](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/). Another [this useful link (although quite old)](http://mohyuddin.blogspot.com/2009/08/persisting-jstree-changes-to-database.html). Sorry for the late reply, am barely here!

Comment: Thank you so much mate, it was really helpful :) really appreciate that, cheers :) The 2nd question; well I meant how I could keep the JSON data to be in sync all the time... so if a FILE was renamed and its parent was changed then the view changes seamlessly and if you were to refresh the page, the result would be the same, so I suppose there would be a ajax request sent/received every time a change takes place... Right! Thanks

Comment: @Farzad, yes, an ajax get/post request has to be made every time the jstree nodes are modified. Care has to taken to handle ajax update failures though. If an ajax request fails then just refresh the jstree and it would repopulate itself with the old data, assuming that you had used json to populate it in the first instance. The state plugin is useful in this case because refreshing a jstree brings back its state, modified or unmodified.